# Referencia variable a objeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, paso-por-referencia

En la función para la creación de un google chart en javascript tengo la variable de un div sobre el cual dibujo el gráfico.

La variable en cuestión es containerDiv, que es un string con el id del div.

Necesitaría, en lugar de dibujar el gráfico propiamente, dibujar un jpg del mismo.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(drawChart, "ready", function () {
                containerDiv.innerHTML = \'<img src="\' + chart.getImageURI() + \'">\';
            });
```

Este código lo encontré en la web,pero no estoy seguro de que esté usandolo apropiadamente.

Como hago para que containerDiv.innerHTML haga referencia al objeto contenido dentro del string containerDiv??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer referencia al **containerDiv** debes buscarlo en tu documento, para ello debes hacer lo siguiente:

***Versión Nativa JS***

```
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("containerDiv")
```

***Versión Jquery***

```
var containerDiv = $("#containerDiv")
```

Claro asumiendo que tu div en cuestión tiene el *id="containerDiv"*, es decir algo como lo siguiente:

```
<div id="containerDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Perfecto! Lo que voy a hacer es, en realidad, lo siguiente: var containerDiv = document.getElementById(containerDiv)